# Browser testing - is it worth testing multiple operating systems?

Tags: testing, browser, cross-browser, cross-platform

I'm about to start some cross browser testing of a design.

In your opinion is it worth testing browsers across a number of operating systems?  As the browser is using the same rendering engine will the design likely be the same or are there inconsistencies big enough to warrant testing on different platforms?

For example, is it worth testing IE9 on Windows 7 and Vista?

Is it worth testing Safari on Mac and Windows?  If I do this is it worth testing on different versions of Windows?

If I test Firefox in Windows is it worth testing on Linux and Mac?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A big **YES**.

I have seen both FireFox and Safari acting differently between Win, Mac and Linux systems.
Specially around places with significant JS and *advanced* CSS implementations.

I personally have not seen differences in IE within different Windows versions.

Comment: Thanks.  That's the kind of thing I was after.

Comment: I have also noticed that Jump To Content links for screen readers for the visually handicapped are not treated properly in firefox on OSX, but works fine in all other operating systems.

Answer (score 8):

I don't think that different version of the same OS influence the page rendering of a given browser.

On the other hand, it would be wise to test the same browser on different OS' as some page elements are OS dependent. Take form inputs and controls for instance. Also Fonts are rendered different based on the OS.

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: **Yes**, especially if there's a lot of Javascript on your page.

Long answer. In my experience, testing web application on the same browser in different versions of Windows did not reveal any significant bugs, specific to an operating system. However it is very fruitful to test your app on Windows and non-windows OS.

Comment: Yeah, we are using JavaScript but it's not too heavy and is using jQuery so cross-browser problems hopefully will be limited.